# Passing parameters to Wordpress static front page

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, htaccess

I have a custom plugin that shows a series of custom posts on a page, i.e.

```
http://www.example.com/permalink/
```

On that page I have a form to filter the posts according to a number of different parameters, and it is passed as:

```
http://www.example.com/permalink/?param1=1&param2=2&param3=3&param4=4&pagi_page=1
```

The problem: If I change that page to be the static front page, the custom posts are still shown, but if I try to apply a filter it loads the posts archive.

I know it has something to do with the permalinks and `.htaccess`, but I have no idea how to solve it. If I turn the permalinks to 'plain' and manually enter the page id it works fine (like this):

```
http://www.example.com/?page_id=6&param1=1&param2=2&param3=3&param4=4&pagi_page=1
```

But if I change the permalinks back to the Post Name it doesn't work.

Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: What’s the code for the form that does the filtering

Comment: Do you have any custom `.htaccess` code?

Comment: My bet would be that your actual parameter names collide with either WordPress internal query variables or with some plugins. Are these the real parameter names? If not, please name the real ones.

Comment: @MrWhite No custom code, just the standard WP stuff. (Thanks for the edits BTW)

Comment: @David You were right, I changed the names of the parameters and it worked a treat. Thanks!